# Can parser split tokens?

Tags: compilers

Is it valid to have the token split up, in a parser; as shown in the below grammar:

```
expr   -> expr addop term
term   -> term mulop factor 
factor -> factor digit | digit
addop  -> + | -
mulop  -> * | /
digit  -> 0 | 1 | ... | 9
```

Say, for the arithmetic expression:

```
12 + 7 * 45 / 9 - 6 + 5
```

for the input: 12, the split of token 12 occurs, in two parts; with first reading digit 1, then 2.

Comment: 12 is not a token here.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I thought any integer value given was a token, even if it was having multiple digits.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Please tell why you removed answer, to my other post.

Comment: @YvesDaoust seems you mean an integrated Parser-lexer, given by the given grammar. So, the terminals are given by: {+, -, *, /, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}. But, request some details on the implementation part, as the use of lookahead in the parser, and how the same lookahead need be communicated to the lexer.

Comment: Why should I request details ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>The arithmetic expression you provided `12 + 7 * 45 / 9 - 6 + 5` will cause the parser to return syntax error because `12` is not part of the language (same problem for `45`...). Specifically, it is not a token and will be recognized as the symbol `1` followed by `2` that is obviously illegal. To manage numbers in the intuitive way you should define a lexer accepting numbers and refer to its language, that is `[0-9+]`.</s>

It is possible to define the language this way, however it is not a best practice and that will have two implications:

1. in case blanks are ignored it is perfectly possible to write $1\underline{ }2 * 3\underline{ }4$ that is equivalent to $12 * 34$. This is generally not what the programmer would expect.
2. you need to carry out integer computation in semantic actions attached to your productions rather than in the lexer; this is possibly a maintainance problem because you are mixing two components that should be separated.

Comment: I disagree with this. 12 parses as a factor (1 is a `digit` is a `factor`; 2 is a `digit`, 12 is a `factor digit` is a `factor`).

Comment: You are right. I glanced at the grammar too quickly: I'll update my answer.